# Why THIS point in the obj?

Tags: javascript, this, scopes

I extremely confusing In forEach loop why the THIS will point to the obj.

I assume will output return this.id is **undefined** , because it called in a lexical function. **THIS** will point it to window.

```
function foo(el) {
  console.log( el, this.id);
}

 var obj = {
   id: "awesome"
 };

 [1, 2, 3].forEach( foo, obj );
 // 1 "awesome" 2 "awesome" 3 "awesome"


 // Easy way to check
 [1, 2, 3].forEach( function(el){
   console.log( el, this.id);
 }, obj);
```

Comment: You explicitly told it to use `obj` as `this`. That's what the second argument to `forEach` is *for*.

Comment: Inside forEach method, the second parameter should for Index of the array. Why Object variable able to use in the second parameter?

Comment: Please see forEach syantax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach The first argument is callback function and second param is value of this while executing callback.

Comment: Great. Sharing the forEach syntax rule.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `Array.prototype.forEach` is the `thisArg`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach which states:

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be used as callback's this value.

Comment: Great.i got it.